# Advanced centering with flexbox (...or without flexbox)

Tags: css, flexbox

Have a look at this dummy code: http://jsbin.com/nabis/1/edit?html,css,output

What I want is the 'home'-item to be in the centre of the page.

Can this be done with Flexbox? Or what other CSS (non-flexbox) solution will get me there?

This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">very long navitem 1</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">very long navitem 2</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item nav__item--home"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">navitem 3</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">navitem 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.nav {
  display: flex; justify-content:center;align-items:center;list-style:none none;  margin:0; padding:0;
}

.nav__item {
  padding: 0 10px;

}

.nav__item--home a {
   display:block;
   width: 75px; 
  height:75px;
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/75x75/000/fff&text=home) no-repeat 0 0;

}
```

Here's an example of what I want to achieve: [example image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bsl8pb2IUAAnydt.png:large)

Comment: Does the `home-item` have a fixed width?

Comment: Please post the significant part of your code in the question, don't just provide a link.

Comment: Have you even tried it using a flexbox? Or are you waiting for a ready implementation?

Comment: - @web-tiki: home-item does has a fixed width

Comment: @Synchro I thought a working example would help explaining the question. Added the HTML/CSS code now

Comment: @feeela Why do you think I didn't tried? As you can see in the link I did!

Answer (score 1):

This little bit of code will center it perfectly:

```
.nav__item--home {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/quwaqowa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for. I want the home-item in the flow of the other navigation-items, but with evenly margins.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving nav: width: 100%;

and then to every element 20% and text-align: center;

There's 5 elements so everything would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is quite an old question and you have probably found your solution by now as you were so close with the code in your example!

To achieve the result you were looking for you simply had to give the `nav__item` an initial width of some value large enough to contain a `very long navitem`.

If you make the following addition to your example the `nav__item--home` will be centred.

`.nav__item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100px;
}`

You are instructing the `nav__items` to *try* be `100px` but if they can not be, then distribute any horizontal space (positive or negative) between themselves **equally**.

There are equal amounts `nav__items` taking up equal amounts of space either side of `nav__item--home`. From this we can assume that the space taken up either side of the middle item is going to be the same, thus deduce the `nav__item--home` (being the middle item) must be in the center.